# Cannot create JSF 2.0 table

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I want to use [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) code and create JSF 2.0 table.

I get this problem when I import the code into Netbeans:

[image]
[image]

How I can fix this code?

Best wishes

**P.S.**  This is the error stack from Netbeans:

```
Source roots:
 /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java
Command line options:
-d /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/target/classes -classpath /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/target/classes:/home/rcbandit/.m2/repository/javax/javaee-web-api/6.0/javaee-web-api-6.0.jar:/home/rcbandit/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.core/4.2.0/org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar:/home/rcbandit/.m2/repository/org/osgi/org.osgi.compendium/4.2.0/org.osgi.compendium-4.2.0.jar:/home/rcbandit/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/osgi-cdi-api/3.1-b41/osgi-cdi-api-3.1-b41.jar: -sourcepath /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java: /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java -s /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/target/generated-sources/annotations -g -nowarn -target 1.7 -source 1.7 -encoding UTF-8 -endorseddirs /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/target/endorsed
Compiling 1 source file to /home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/target/classes
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[52,24] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
 actual and formal argument lists differ in length
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[60,17] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
 actual and formal argument lists differ in length
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[61,17] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
 actual and formal argument lists differ in length
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[62,17] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
 actual and formal argument lists differ in length
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[68,65] error: cannot find symbol
 class Item
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[68,12] error: cannot find symbol
 variable item of type Item
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[70,15] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
 actual and formal argument lists differ in length
com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[80,15] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
8 errors 
-------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.939s
Finished at: Sat Mar 31 17:29:51 EEST 2012
Final Memory: 16M/162M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project History-Module-57: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[52,24] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[60,17] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[61,17] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[62,17] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[68,65] error: cannot find symbol
class Item
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[68,12] error: cannot find symbol
variable item of type Item
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[70,15] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/home/rcbandit/Desktop/NetBeans/Prototype_13/History_Module_57/src/main/java/com/DX_57/HM_57/Application.java:[80,15] error: constructor Item in class Item cannot be applied to given types;
-> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project History-Module-57: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more


For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is the problem hint in Netbeand when I move the cursor on     `private Item item = new Item();`

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I can hardly read whats on the screenshots. Please post only the code that is producing errors and say what errors there are.

Comment: In FF click right button and click "View Image". You will find the code at the link

Comment: Erm, no, sorry. That is not how questions are asked around here. Netbeans clearly states compiler errors that you should include in your question as **text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement your own Item class as stated on site :

> The Item class is just a simple model object, its code should be straightforward enough. A Serializable Javabean with two properties Long id and String value, a default constructor and a constructor filling both properties...

You are actually using a javax.mail.FetchProfile.Item

So implement your **own** simple Item class as stated on site, import it and everything will be fine.
Hope it helped !